# What's an effective way to merge arrays based on the nth element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, optimization

This is relatively straightforward, but it's bugging me that I can't find a more elegant solution.

Say you have an array of n-dimensional arrays, and you want to just squash together the arrays that have a matching mth, element by some method, let's say addition.

Example: `[[1, 100], [1, 200], [2, 100], [2, 105], [3, 202], [4, 133]]`

Result:
`[[1, 300], [2, 205], [3, 202], [4, 133]]`

The solution I came up with seems *really* inelegant to me. Is there some way to do this with way less code, or in a much more efficient way?

```js
function mergePairs(originalArray) {
  const newArray = [];
  originalArray.forEach((pair) => {
    const foundPair = newArray.find((newPair) => {
      return newPair[0] === pair[0];
    });
    if (foundPair) {
      foundPair[1] += pair[1];
    } else {
      newArray.push(pair);
    }
  });
  return newArray;
}
```

Aside: If there's a cheeky one-liner in lodash that accomplishes the same thing in a super inefficient way, I'm happy with that too.

Comment: If you search for "merge objects based on a property" you will get a lot more results than looking for the special case of array objects.

Comment: Considering your code already achieves the desired result, this question may be more suitable for [**StackExchange's CodeReview**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead :)

Comment: how is m determined? is it a constant given at the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

You might use `reduce` and `map` for your specific case:

```js
function mergePairs (originalArray) {
  const o = originalArray.reduce((a, e) => (a[e[0]] = ~~a[e[0]] + e[1]) && a, {});
  return Object.keys(o).map(k => [+k, o[k]]);
}

console.log(mergePairs ([[1, 100], [1, 200], [2, 100], [2, 105], [3, 202], [4, 133]]))
```

Comment: Reduce is a great idea and this should be significantly faster than OP's method (only `O(n)`). But it might be nice to be a bit more verbose in the callback return—it's not easy to read.

Comment: @ChrisChudzicki What makes you think that `reduce` is faster than `forEach`?

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure what the relative speeds of `reduce` and `forEach` are. But the OP's method had a nested loop: `forEach` element of the original array, `find` an element of the new array. For a length `n` array with `k` distinct first keys, this would, I believe, be `O(kn)`. The reduce method here is, I believe, only `O(n)`.

Comment: @ChrisChudzicki Yes, but the key here is the usage of the object as the lookup map in the loop, vs the nested loop. It doesn't have anything to do with `reduce` specifically.

Comment: @Bergi I agree! My original comment had two unrelated statements—it could have been worded better :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are only sorting numbers, and you expect the array to be sorted in ascending order already (like your example):

```
function mergePairs(arr) {
  return arr.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[0] === b[0]){
      a[1] += b[1];
      b[0] = 'del'
    }
  }).filter(val => val[0] !== 'del');
}
```

Or you could sort it to be safe:

```
function mergePairs(arr) {
  arr.sort((a, b) => a[0] === b[0]);
  return arr.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[0] === b[0]){
      a[1] += b[1];
      b[0] = 'del'
    }
  }).filter(val => val[0] !== 'del');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I find it makes more sense to split the pairs up then recombine.  I use indexOf the matching array as it is more efficient to look through than the entire original array list.  Each time I come across a new value, I add it to match list.  The match values can be anything, not just numbers, and don't have to avoid any keywords.  The ~ converts -1 from not found into 0 which is falsey.

```
function combine (complexArray){
    var matches = [];
    var totals = [];

    complexArray.forEach(simplify);

    function simplify(item) {
        var match = matches.indexOf(item[0]);
        if(~match) {
            totals[match] += item[1];
        } else {
            matches.push(item[0]);
            totals.push(item[1]);
        }
    }

    return matches.map(function(value, index) {
        return [value, totals[index]];
    });
}
```